# Code not running in Hackerrank though it is running in onlinegdb

Tags: c++14, hashtable, buffer-overflow

The main topic is to write a code in C++ for  Hash with Chaining (using single link list).here, data has been provided in terms of array of long datatype and we have to store them in hash(table size 13) in a sorted manner.

Here is my code for the same.
https://onlinegdb.com/B1pbgjxAI

There is no compiler error in the code but while running the code the following error arises.

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./Solution terminated
Reading symbols from Solution...done.
[New LWP 86657]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./Solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

Here, for the testcase, input is

> 201911169

and the output should be

> 93

Answer (score 1):

In line 36 you're calling `strcpy(p->name,Name)`, but `Name` is passed from `x` in `main`, and `char x[4]` isn't null-terminated as you only assign to `x[j]` for `j` from 2 downto 0. Add a statement `x[3] = '\0';`.